# Laravel blade section and yield. yield does not work well

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am a biginner of Laravel blade.

I wanted to split index.blade.php.
When the contents of morumoru.blade.php modal.blade.php are on index.html.it works well.

/view/camila/cabelo/index.blade.php

```
@yield('camila.cabelo.morumoru')

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
SAMPLE
</button>

@yield('camila.cabelo.blade')
```

/view/camila/cabelo/morumoru.blade.php

```
@section('morumoru.blade')

<ul>
    <li><a href="/star">INDEX</a></li>
    <li><a href="/star/sun">SUN</a></li>
    <li><a href="/star/moon">MOON</a></li>
</ul>

@endsection
```

/view/camila/cabelo/modal.blade.php

```
@section('modal')
<!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">...</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

use `@include('camila.cabelo.morumoru')` and `@include('camila.cabelo.modal')` instead of @yield

Comment: Nothing changed....

Answer (score 0):

use include instead of yield, and remove @section also @endsection from blade files

Top include like this @include('camila.cabelo.morumoru')
Bottom include like this @include('camila.cabelo.modal')